# refresh access token for google calendar api using javascript (react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, oauth-2.0, google-api

i am using the google calendar api to write events to my organization's calendar, but i cannot figure out how to refresh the access token so that my program can use the calendar for more than an hour at a time.

to recreate the error:

1. generate oauth client id and client secret from your project's google cloud console
2. select calendar and calender.events scope at https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground
3. exchange the **Authorization Code** generated by Google's OAuth Playground for a **refresh token** and a temporary **access token**
4. list https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground as a valid redirect uri for your client on your project's cloud console
5. attempt to refresh your **access token** using your client id and client secret from your cloud console

**THE PROBLEM**

Google's OAuth playground access token expires after 3600s (1hr). I am able to refresh the access token using google's stand-in client credentials, but when I try to make the request (either from the playground itself or from postman), I am met with the following error message

```
{
  "error_description": "Unauthorized", 
  "error": "unauthorized_client"
}
```

I have verified that the oauth playground is listed as a valid redirect uri for my client in the cloud console. I have also compared my POST request to the one google sends when refreshing the **access token** with placeholder credentials to ensure that I am sending all necessary params.

**REQUESTS/RESPONSES**

**POST request on Oauth playground using google's default client credentials**

```
POST /token HTTP/1.1
Host: oauth2.googleapis.com
Content-length: 223
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
user-agent: google-oauth-playground
client_secret=************&grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=1%2F%2F04qg5N0zhIRbPCgYIARAAGAQSNwF-L9IrTEZny7y_4wpbjLUh7ImtWRu473AQeTG3NG49ogQVzDZJe99BnS1TwFjwX7S2mNbLOYQ&client_id=407408718192.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

**Response from Google's oauth playground when making the above request**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-length: 385
X-xss-protection: 0
X-content-type-options: nosniff
Transfer-encoding: chunked
Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Vary: Origin, X-Origin, Referer
Server: scaffolding on HTTPServer2
-content-encoding: gzip
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Date: Wed, 31 Aug 2022 22:13:53 GMT
X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
Alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
{
  "access_token": "ya29.a0AVA9y1sTkPpmJIHvIBNODwdXr36hzumPEmoJGFBB1y29SZVwiE_QBy7RuTjDNzPkKyBOJ7RD1LBceTooeUZuNl-wN5dkyqsjFF5ynMkcShwG_yADXazPUFXngsSGuW_WRuVR01s9FOnv2N5gzkPldvQEtLaZaCgYKATASAQASFQE65dr8ZDuFe5BQyBG8ostdxK5ObQ0163", 
  "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar", 
  "expires_in": 3599, 
  "token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

**POST request to google's Oauth playground using MY client credentials**

```
POST /token HTTP/1.1
Host: oauth2.googleapis.com
Content-length: 279
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
user-agent: google-oauth-playground
client_secret=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&grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=1%2F%2F04qg5N0zhIRbPCgYIARAAGAQSNwF-L9IrTEZny7y_4wpbjLUh7ImtWRu473AQeTG3NG49ogQVzDZJe99BnS1TwFjwX7S2mNbLOYQ&client_id=804898855072-r91v64ojblf83if1pe9f8vr4mumubecc.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

**Response from Google's oauth playground when making the above request**

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-length: 75
X-xss-protection: 0
X-content-type-options: nosniff
Transfer-encoding: chunked
Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Vary: Origin, X-Origin, Referer
Server: scaffolding on HTTPServer2
-content-encoding: gzip
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Date: Wed, 31 Aug 2022 22:16:15 GMT
X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
Alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
{
  "error_description": "Unauthorized", 
  "error": "unauthorized_client"
}
```

Any guidance is greatly appreciated. Google seriously needs some better docs!

Comment: Also, I'll be using an entirely different project space when I deploy this application, so that's why the client secret and client id are visible.

Comment: Could you find any written proof from Google that the access token expires within 1 hour? I also encountered the same issue after 1 hour. But if I can get any written information from Google regarding that it will be much worth I think.

Answer (score 0):

unauthorized_client

Normally means that the client id and client secrete you are using with a refresh token is not the client id and client secret that were used to create it.

You should not be using playground to create tokens. You should be creating them in your app and refreshing them in your app.

Remember you can not refresh an token using a client side language.  I am not a reactJs dev so if this is running client side that could also be the cause of your error.  Use a server sided language.